# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, dataset

I am developing a VB.NET application with SQL Server 2008 and I get the above error when I try to run this ASPX file.  What is the cause?

Error details:

> Exception Details:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: The
>   SqlParameterCollection only accepts
>   non-null SqlParameter type objects.
>   Parameter name: value

Code below:

```
            Dim DSTableData As New System.Data.DataSet

            If check1.Checked Then
                DSTableData = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.FillSparePartsTable(1)
            Else
                DSTableData = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.FillSparePartsTable(0)
            End If

            dgTable.DataSource = DSTableData
            dgTable.DataBind()

...
        Public Shared Function FillSparePartsTable(ByVal check1 As Integer) As DataSet
            Dim DSPageData As New System.Data.DataSet
            Dim param(1) As SqlClient.SqlParameter

            param(0) = New SqlParameter("@check1", SqlDbType.Int)
            param(0).Value = check1

            ''# A Using block will ensure the .Dispose() method is called for these variables, even if an exception is thrown 
            ''# This is IMPORTANT - not disposing your connections properly can result in an unrespsonsive database 
            Using conn As New SQLConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("AMDMetricsDevConnectionString")), _
           cmd As New SQLCommand("FillSparePartsTable", conn), _
            da As New SQLDataAdapter(cmd)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param)

                da.Fill(DSPageData)
            End Using

            Return DSPageData
        End Function

USE [AMDMetrics]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[FillSparePartsTable]    Script Date: 05/16/2011 07:48:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FillSparePartsTable]
@check1 INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

If @check1 = 1
     SELECT 
        A.PART_NUM AS PN, 
        A.PART_DESC, 
        CASE ISNULL(A.NUM_FAILED, '') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE A.NUM_FAILED END AS numFailed, 
        ISNULL(A.AVG_CENSUS, 0) AS AvgCensus, 
        CASE ISNULL(B.Multiplier, '') WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE B.Multiplier END AS PartMultiplier, 
        CASE ISNULL(AVG_CENSUS, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE    
           CAST(1 - (CASE ISNULL(A.NUM_FAILED, '') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE A.NUM_FAILED END / 
           (CASE ISNULL(B.Multiplier, '') WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE B.Multiplier END * AVG_CENSUS)) AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) END AS ReliabilityRate,    
       A.PRIORITY , 
       B.Criticality    
      FROM [PROC].SPARE_PART_RELIABILITY A LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUAL.SPARE_PARTS_CRITICALITY B ON    
      dbo.FORMAT_PART(A.PART_NUM) = dbo.FORMAT_PART(B.[Part Number])    
        WHERE (A.QUERY_DATE = DateAdd(ms, -5, DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(m, 0, DateAdd(mm, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0)) 
        AND CASE ISNULL(AVG_CENSUS, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE    
            CAST(1 - (CASE ISNULL(A.NUM_FAILED, '') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE A.NUM_FAILED END / 
            (CASE ISNULL(B.Multiplier, '') WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE B.Multiplier END * AVG_CENSUS)) AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) END < 0.98)    
        ORDER BY A.PRIORITY, ReliabilityRate 
Else
    SELECT 
        A.PART_NUM AS PN, 
        A.PART_DESC, 
        CASE ISNULL(A.NUM_FAILED, '') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE A.NUM_FAILED END AS numFailed, 
        ISNULL(A.AVG_CENSUS, 0) AS AvgCensus, 
        CASE ISNULL(B.Multiplier, '') WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE B.Multiplier END AS PartMultiplier, 
        CASE ISNULL(AVG_CENSUS, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE    
           CAST(1 - (CASE ISNULL(A.NUM_FAILED, '') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE A.NUM_FAILED END / 
           (CASE ISNULL(B.Multiplier, '') WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE B.Multiplier END * AVG_CENSUS)) AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) END AS ReliabilityRate,    
       A.PRIORITY , 
       B.Criticality    
      FROM [PROC].SPARE_PART_RELIABILITY A LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUAL.SPARE_PARTS_CRITICALITY B ON    
      dbo.FORMAT_PART(A.PART_NUM) = dbo.FORMAT_PART(B.[Part Number])    
        WHERE(A.QUERY_DATE = DateAdd(ms, -5, DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(m, 0, DateAdd(mm, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0)))    
        ORDER BY A.PRIORITY, ReliabilityRate
```

Comment: I found that not using BEGIN ... END inside  IF statements in T-SQL can end up in tears... IF Blah = Something BEGIN ... Code ... END ELSE BEGIN ... Code END

Comment: Thanks for your tip!  Oded found the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause appears to be fairly obvious from the exception message.

You are adding null values to the `SqlParameterCollection`.

Here:

```
Dim param(1) As SqlClient.SqlParameter
```

You declare an array with 2 items, but you only ever populate the first - `param(0)`.

The second one - `param(1)` is null.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that!  Thanks!